# Solving Language Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to know about how to retrieve data from map.

I have three button.

Register, Update and Delete from Jsp page.

There are two JSP. First.jsp and Second.jsp.

I included first.jsp in  second.jsp.`aaa`

The buttons are in second.jsp.

At First.jsp.

I have combobox for language change. It must be change language only when click button.

There are two language English and Japanese.

I send API class using ajax according to language id. If id=1(Japanese) and id=2(English).

I Wrote ajax api inside of combobox change function. Below is my code.

```
 $.ajax({
        url : 'aa/idsend',
        cache : false,
        type : 'GET',
        dataType : 'json',
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data : "lid="+select,
              success: function(data) {
               },
            });
```

I receive data from server the following format.

```
{data = Object {1: "Would you like to register?", 2: "Would you like to update?", 3: "Would you like to delete?"}
```

Above data are come from database. If I add new data into database the id become 4:"something have".

I want to know how to retrieve these data according button click event.
If click register button I want to take register sentence only. The other is also like that.

Comment: you have to send same way like above ajax call, while register button click sent register with URL so that on server side , server can know what to send into response.

Comment: Why have you set `contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
`? You are making a GET request, there is no content in the request body to describe the type of.

Comment: "I receive data from server the following format" — It would make life a lot easier if you expressed it in JSON instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be GET method also, but i prefer POST.

```
function ajaxRequest(dataObj, cbFunc) {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'aa/idsend',
        data: dataObj
    }).done(function(dataFromServer) {
        cbFunc(dataFromServer);
    });
}

function useData(dataFS) {
    //do something with data from server dataFS
}

function getCurrentLanguage() {
  var cL = 'en';//default language
  //some code to get language from checkboxes
  return cL
}

$('.button').on('click', function(e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id'),
        jsonData = {},
        curLang = getCurrentLanguage();

    switch (id) {
        case 'register' :
            jsonData = {req: 'register', lang: curLang};
            break;
        case 'update' :
            jsonData = {req: 'update', lang: curLang};
            break;
        case 'delete' :
            jsonData = {req: 'delete', lang: curLang};
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    ajaxRequest(jsonData, useData);
});
```

Then in the aa/idsend serverside script you can prepare data to send according to req POST variable received. Now you even don't need to send back questions like 'Would you like to register?'. Instead you can do action according to req value and send back information about the operation - Success! or Fail!

Comment: Thank you in advance for your suggestion. I will try your way.